# Progress bar HTML5/PHP

Tags: php, html, web

Edit 30-04-2015 19:52 (+1 GMT)
What I have used is:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Now all I see is 70% complete, not an actual progress bar. :(

This is the code:

```
<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
        <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you have tried and why it didn't work, then we can see more clearly what it is that you are struggling with and help you from there =]

Comment: Hmmm... I think you misunderstand me, the point I am making is that your Question is not a question. There is no specific problem to resolve (I know you have a problem to resolve but you aren't actually addressing it here). You're a new user so this is meant to help you improve your use of this site, it isn't meant as an insult or rebuke. You state that "It didn't work", you need to expand on why it didn't so you can be helped. We can't see your code unless you show it, we can't know the details unless you explicitly tell us. Perhaps re-read the "Useful Question" guide. =]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question to fix the formatting and some typos.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: 50
    });
  });
  </script>
```

put the desired value in `value:50` change the value from `50` to whatever and see the result

Comment: @Waylon194 have u included `jquery library`